# Specific differential equation with initial conditions

Tags: differential

I have diff. equation :   $ y'' +2y' = (y')^2 e ^x  , y(0)=3, y'(0)=1 $,  and i have problem with solving that. I used substitution $ u(x)=y' $ and i got bernoulli's diff. equation. I solved  that and got   $ y'=[(1/2)*e^x +D*e^{2y'}]^{-1} $ and that is basically confounded differential equation. Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $u=y'$, the problem becames
$$\begin{cases}
 u'+2u=u^2 \operatorname {e}^x \\
u(0)=1
\end{cases}
$$
which, as you said, is indeed a Bernoulli equation. If we divided by $u^2$ we get
$$
\frac{u'}{u^2} + \frac{2}{u} = \operatorname e^{x}
$$ and now, after the substitution $v=\frac{1}{u}$, we obtain
$$
v'-2v=-\mathrm e^{x}
$$

That has solution
$$
v(x) = c\operatorname e^{2x}+\operatorname e^{x}=\operatorname e^{x} \left(c\cdot \operatorname e^x +1\right)
$$

Therefore
$$
u(x)= \frac{1}{\operatorname e^{x} \left(c\cdot \operatorname e^x +1\right)} = \frac{\operatorname e^{-x}}{c\cdot \operatorname e^x +1}
$$

Now, if we impose $u(0)=1$, we found

$$
u(0) = \frac{1}{c+1}=1\implies c = 0
$$

Hence the solution is $u(x)=\operatorname{e}^{-x}$.

Finally

$$
y(x)=-\operatorname{e}^{-x}+c
$$

And, imposing $y(0)=3$, we have

$$
y(x)=4-\operatorname{e}^{-x}
$$

Comment: thanks, I must have missed something while i was solving brenoulli equation  :)